# Will it ruin the original meaning of the quote if I replace "the other day" with "a few days ago"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-difference

Happy New Year all!

I was watching Sailormoon on Youtube. The ending was sad. After that, I began to do some reading on Wikipedia about Sailormoon. When I saw the first release date of Sailormoon (it was 1992 and it is 2016 now), I suddenly started to moan that time passed so quickly. 
I stopped reading the Wikipedia page and visited Google for some quotes about time, and then I came across this quote of Perry Como,

> **Just the other day**, it seems, the kids were running through the house,
>   slamming doors, breaking glass, making noise. Time goes by so quickly.
>   Sometimes everything seems so fleeting.

At first, I was not very sure about the meaning of **Just the other day** in the quote, so I looked it up in Cambridge dictionary, and it told me that 
the other day means **a few days ago**.

When I was finding some way to help me remember this quote, I came up with this question

> Will it ruin the original meaning of the quote if I replace "the other
>   day" with "a few days ago"?

Thank you.

Comment: "Just the other day" as used here is a set phrase used to reminisce about  past events. In this case probably years ago. You might add when this was written, but I suspect it was after his kids grew up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, **just the other day** and **a few days ago** are mostly **interchangeable in recounting** something from the **past**.

However, substituting **just the other day** with **a few days ago** in your quote from Perry Como **would change** its meaning. This difference is determined by the additional phrase **it seems**.

**A few days ago** is **countable** and usually means more than 2 days(a couple) but less than 7 days(a week).  **Just the other day** tends to be more **indeterminate** in time

> **A few days ago** the kids had sandwiches for lunch.  *(within the last week)*
>   **Just the other day** the kids had sandwiches for lunch. *(possibly a month or more)*

When **it seems** is added, the meaning changes for **just the other day**. **It seems** is added for contrast since *something* feels recent but in actuality is not.  This construction is used for **recounting an experience** or **memory**.

> It seems like **a few days ago** we fell in love.
>   It seems like **just the other day** we fell in love.

**Just the other day** can also be used as a time shorter than **a few days ago** (confused yet?)

> It seems like **just the other day** we fell in love.
>   It seems like **yesterday** we fell in love.
>   It seems like **a few days ago** we fell in love.

The first two are more equivalent and mean the memory seems **fresher** than the third.

A choice would be to use **a few days ago** to recount a **specific event** and **just the other day** to recount a **general recollection**.  Both are phrases which are heavily **dependent on context**.

Comment: Great answer @Peter. If I could up-vote more than once, I would.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like **just the other day** C was in the vanguard, now it's all Java, Ruby, Python (built on C...)

Comment: It has just hit me that "just the other day" means: recent in memory, but not necessarily in time, while "a few days ago" means recently in time.

Comment: I hope it did't hurt when it **hit** you :)